# ReactiveCocoa :: Can I subscribe to a signal inside a createsignal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, reactive-cocoa

We are having some problems trying to get `CLLocationManager`working with iOS8.

The idea is that we have a `LocationManager` that handles all location related stuff. Since iOS8 the ask for permissions deal is asynchronous, so when we try to get a location we might not have received permissions yet.

To work this around we want to do it in a two-step fashion:

- First check if we already have authorization. If so, tell the subscriber `completed`.
- Otherwise, start updating, which will ask for permission. Once the user replied, get the status from the callback. If YES, send `completed`. If NO, send `error`.

In the code below, `self.authorizationStatusSignal` is observing the callback `didChangeAuthorizationStatus`, so it will trigger whenever the user decides to give permission (or not).

The thing is that, upon subscribing to that signal inside the creation method, the `subscriber` has lost reference and the `completed` is never delivered.

Is it possible to subscribe like this inside the creation? We tried strongifying it but nothing happened.

```
- (RACSignal *)authorizationSignal {

return [[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

    if ([self authorized:@([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus])]) {
        [subscriber sendCompleted];

    } else {
        [self.authorizationStatusSignal subscribeNext:^(RACTuple * args) {

            if ([self authorized:(NSNumber *)args.second]) {
                [subscriber sendCompleted];
            } else {
                [subscriber sendError:nil];
            }
        }];
    }
    return nil;
}] replayLast];
}
```

Comment: Did you check `self.authorizationStatusSignal` really send next? I tried your code and its worked.

Comment: Hi Ken, yeah it seems the signal is connected fine. But for some reason the completed never gets to the subscribers block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the idea proposed by @kenKuan we did another check that hadn't think about. The problem lies in the sendError that is executing (though it shouldn't reach that instance) before we can actually send completed. This way, it prevents the sendcompleted from actually reaching the subscriber.